# Why Boolean always giving null

Tags: java, oop, syntax, null, boolean

I have written the following code

```
Boolean isit;

if(isit== true) {
    System.out.println("isit is true");
} else {
    System.out.println("isit is not false");
}
```

but it's always null ,but it should give false as `default`..

Comment: `boolean` is `false` by default, and `Boolean` like ALL reference types is `null` by default.  IMHO, use primitives instead of the wrappers unless you really need to use a wrapper.  BTW You can't use `==` to compare Boolean, you need to use equals, and you wouldn't use it for `boolean` either as it redundant.

Answer (score 20):

When you declare it as a `Boolean` (note the capital letter), it is an object, therefore `null` by default.

I think you meant to make it a `boolean`, not a `Boolean`.

Furthermore, with a `boolean` you could just do:

```
boolean isit;
if (isit) {
    System.out.println("isit is true");
} else {
    System.out.println("isit is false");
}
//prints "isit is false"
```

Answer (score 10):

Unlike `boolean` primitive that has two states, namely, `true` and `false`, a wrapper `Boolean` has an additional third state of `null`. When the `Boolean` object is `null`, it is neither `true` nor `false`.

When you compare the object for equality to `true`, the value gets wrapped as `Boolean`, and gets compared to `null`. The result is `false`. The same thing would happen if you compare it to `false`, however: the code below will not print anything.

```
Boolean isit = null;
if (isit == true) { // true gets converted to Boolean.TRUE
    System.out.println("isit is true")
}
if (isit == false) { // false gets converted to Boolean.FALSE
    System.out.println("isit is false")
}
```

If you need three states in your flags (`true`, `false`, and "not set") you should use `Boolean`; in cases when you need only two states (`true` and `false`) you should stay with the primitive data type of `boolean`.

Answer (score 4):

you are using a wrapper class `object` then never forget to initialize it to a `default` value. As by default all `wrapper class` objects are initialized to null.

you have to intialize like

```
  Boolean B =  Boolean.TRUE;   
  Boolean B = true;
```

or take a primitive value

```
 boolean isit;  ///default false
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code will never compile and it will give an error like `The local variable isit may not have been initialized`.

`Boolean` is a wrapper class,not primitive data type. As you just initialize the variable as

```
Boolean isit;
```

and not assign any values it will never compile.
But if you use primitive type boolean like:

```
boolean isit;
```

then if you assigned nothing then by default the value will be false.

```
boolean isit;

if(isit) {
    System.out.println("isit is true");
} else {
    System.out.println("isit is false");
}
```

This will have isit value as false.

Comment: It's a nit, but `if(isit)` is cleaner. The `else` should say `isit is false`

Answer (score 2):

**Because...**

**INPUT :**

```
Boolean object;
boolean primitive;

System.out.println(object); 
System.out.println(primitive);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
null
false
```

---

- **`Boolean`** is an object.

  - If it's not assigned with some value, its value will be `null` by default.

On the other hand,

- **`boolean`** is a primitive type.

  - If it's not assigned with some value, its value will be `false` by default

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is a wrapper class object. and as java convention `object's default value is always null`. if you used boolean with b small letter then it's call as a primitive and it's value as you understand it's value `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

well in this case you have to initiallize isit-variable value to either to true/false, othervise the compiler will not let you compile the code, coz u are using isit-variable in IF with out giving it some value.
in java a variable must have been initalized before it can be used.